# Whats wrong with the following android code?

Tags: android

I am trying to compare the type of calls with 'missed' calls.

I am using `CallLog.Calls.TYPE` to do this, but the I don't get desired output inside the app.

Below is the code.

```
 if (Integer.parseInt(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)==CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE) {
     dir = "MISSED";
     sb.append("\nName: " + namee + "\nPhone Number:  " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:  " + dir + " \nCall Date:   " + callDayTime
                            + " \nCall duration in sec :   " + callDuration);

 }
```

Comment: I want to know that am i doing the comparison in the right way ??

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I want to list all missed calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing correctly. You are comparing the constants. You need to compare with the values inside the `Cursor` you fetched using `ContentResolver` like this

If `cursor` is the result of your query then do this

```
String callType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE));
```

and then

```
if(Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE ){
    dir = "MISSED";
    sb.append("\nName: " + namee + "\nPhone Number:  " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:  " + dir + " \nCall Date:   " + callDayTime
                        + " \nCall duration in sec :   " + callDuration);
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.